# create image of custom list view with total list items in android programmatically

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

For creating image of custom listview created bitmap of each list item and created one big bitmap by recycle all small bitmaps but while creating big bitmap app is freezing and if user scrolls the listview during bigbitmap creation image is not creating properly,i followed all stackoverflow links which are related to take screenshot of listview but not able to solve this issue.
here is my code to create bigbitmap. please help

```
    // View childView=null;

    ListAdapter adapter = null;

    try {

        // listview = Result_Activity.mFocusedListView;
        adapter = mFocusedListView.getAdapter();
        int itemscount = adapter.getCount();
        System.out.println("itemscount" + itemscount);
        int allitemsheight = 0;
        List<Bitmap> bmps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

        // This loop is for Getting height of the list view
        for (int i = 0; i < itemscount; i++) {

            System.out.println("i " + i);
            System.out.println("ilistview " + mFocusedListView);
            System.out.println("height og listview  "
                    + mFocusedListView.getHeight());
            childView = adapter.getView(i, mFocusedListView, null);

            System.out.println("child view " + childView);
            // setting height and width for child view
            childView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    mFocusedListView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    mFocusedListView.getMeasuredHeight(),
                    MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            // Setting Layout for child view
            childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    childView.getMeasuredHeight());
            childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            childView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            // System.out.println("array size  ="+bmps.size());

            allitemsheight += childView.getMeasuredHeight();

            System.out.println("all item, height" + allitemsheight);

        }
        // Creating a big bitmap height of as listview
        bigbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                mFocusedListView.getMeasuredWidth(), allitemsheight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        // Setting color to bitmap
        bigbitmap.eraseColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

        // System.out.println("bigbitmap "+bigbitmap);

        int height = 0;
        // loop for getting view for every item in list view
        for (int j = 0; j < itemscount; j++) {

            System.out.println("i " + j);
            System.out.println("height is " + height);

            childView = adapter.getView(j, mFocusedListView, null);

            // Settting height and width for childView

            childView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    mFocusedListView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    mFocusedListView.getMeasuredHeight(),
                    MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

            childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    childView.getMeasuredHeight());
            childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            // setting backgroung color to white
            childView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

            Bitmap bb = childView.getDrawingCache();
            bigbitmap2 = overlay(bigbitmap, bb, height);
            // storeImage(bb, "textdcjsajkl"+j+".png");
            height = height + bb.getHeight();
        }
        // Storing Image in SD card
        storeImage(bigbitmap2,
                "BigBitmap" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bigbitmap;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you need exactly do this, but you are creating a big bitmap (by retrieving first each listview item heigth), then for each listview item you create another bitmap to add it to the big bitmap... Do you think that this process have big possibilities of freeze the screen? Handle bitmaps requires a big amount of memory. I hqve not tested the code but maybe you should try to optimize the whole process or use AsyncTask to avoid block the main thread.

First of all, try to retrieve the bitmap of each view with this method:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) { 
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap); 
        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null) bgDrawable.draw(canvas); 
        else 
             canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE); view.draw(canvas); 
        return returnedBitmap; 
}
```

And make this task using an AsyncTask, not in the main thread.

Comment: Could you suggest alternative way ,i ll try that.i am trying this because i felt it is only option after searching in stackoverflow.

Comment: What is exactly the task that you must performe?

Comment: i need to create a image of total listview and save it in gallery.

Comment: See the edit question. Sorry for the format, I'm using the mobile app :/